# Production of hypoclorous acid by salt water electrolysis: requesting tips

Tags: acid-base, electrolysis, halogens

I wish to use commonly available perfume ultrasonic nebulizers/diffusers to "fog" my working environment with hypoclorous acid, to obtain full coverage (ish) disinfection, albeit slowly.
I also wish to avoid falling victim to the price gauging of everything disinfectant-related during this particular period.

I did my research, and I noticed the most accessible method of HOCl synthesis is by eletrolyzing an ideally saturated solution of NaCl.
I am no chemist, but my work is health related, and I am a DIY enthusiast.
These are the info and tips I got from my research:

1. First and foremost, avoid stainless steel electrodes (or rather, anode) as the release of hexavalent chromium with fxck you up
2. You might use two different cups where the same saturated salt solution is poured, and obtain electrical continuity by using an "electrode bridge" between the two, so there is a better separation (albeit non complete) of chlorine and NaOH production
3. by this reaction, other than HOCl, you will also obtain unaltered gaseous chlorine (which gives the characteristic chlorine smell when standing close to the vat), and chloridric acid (HCl); to reduce the amount of chrloridric acid produced in the reaction you can add "some" acid into the solution, usually vinegar is suggested, but I suppose lemon juice (to give a better smell) and citric acid (to give no smell at all) could work as well
4. graphite anodes are the cheapest among the "cleanest" anodes (including here gold and platinum), which will release the least "pollutants" in the solution, even if they do release CO, CO2, and flakes of graphite; I experimented that you can use reclaimed old batteries as graphite electrodes, but since they are tiny, they will fleck off really fast
5. I noticed that if you use common iron electrodes, the solution will be heavily polluted with rust particles (FeO) and coloured with a strong orange, but if left to rest for the night, there will be a very good sedimentation process, and the morning after you will be left with a clear liquid in the vat, and an orange deposit on the bottom, which makes for way faster separation
6. Using a bench power supply, I can get it to the max 5A output quite easily by increasing the output voltage (so inputting at least 50W worth of power into the electrolysis reaction), since I use large iron bars that offer larger contact surface with the solution, and after a short while I notice that the unsoluted NaCl resting on the bottom of the vat will start dissolving
7. I tested dropping a small quantity of hydrogen peroxide in the obtained solution, and no foaming occurs, which I would expect to happen with NaOCl

Now come the questions:

1. Will having the FeO polluted solution rest overnight to sediment, alter the content, as in reduce its HOCl concentration? Is it light-unstable, should I cover it or place it in a dark container?
2. Is there an easy method to determine the HOCl "concentration"? Using quotation marks here, as I do not expect to have precise values, just a layman idea of "how much HOCl really is in there"
3. Should I be worried about the presence of HCl in the solution when I place it in my ultrasonic fogger? Also, if I do not separate the vats of anode and catode, hence obtaining a solution containing both HOCl and NaOH, should I be worried about fogging? I am talking about a populated rooms, not a vacated one.
4. Will pumping 50W+ in the vat create the conditions for a dangerous outcome, or is the heating up of the solution the only consequence?
5. If I keep the current flowing in the solution even after all the dissolved salt has been electrolyzed, will I mess up anything? I notice that the bubbling at the electrodes goes on for a while even after all the unsoluted salt on the bottom of the vat dissolves, and I cannot really hang out in front of the vat for the whole time to check on it, so I'd rather leave it on and fuggedaboudit until some kind of alarm I set sounds.
6. Are the any inaccuracies in the premises I made above, before my questions?

Nothing else comes to mind for now, thank you for your attention!

Comment: I understand that being a newcomer I might have failed observing some kind of "rule", yet I tried to make this question the most complete and useful possible by adding all information I had (researched)... so I would at least expect a comment explaining why you downvoted it.

Comment: I would fear to breathe a strong oxydizing fog more than I fear coronavirus. Neither will do any good to your lungs. Stick to washing your hands and using a mask. Inhaling hypoclorous acid would probably kill you or get you severely ill faster than any virus.

Comment: every source I found for HOCl safety states that it's breathable, and I think everyone breathes it when under a swimming pool dome, also the compound is naturally produced by animals as a defense mechanism. I am not worried about inhaling a HOCl fog itself, more about inhaling something else that might be in the solution due to improper synthesis methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Cool idea employing the ultrasonic nebulizers/diffusers.

However, as I have elsewhere cited this work, ['Generation of Hydroxyl Radicals from Dissolved Transition Metals in Surrogate Lung Fluid Solutions'](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2626252/) by Edgar Vidrio relating to lung cancer likely induced from dust particles (containing transition metals) interact with O2 leading to reactive oxygen species and powerful/problematic hydroxyl radicals, be aware that what you are working with (HOCl versus H2O2) is as (or more) problematical from a health perspective, so good ventilation with a gas mask is strongly recommended if you elect to proceed.

My thoughts, you do not have to worry about the HOCl concentration (which can be dilute when sourced from electrolysis) if you managed to imbed say a chemical/electrochemical hydroxyl radical presence (which can be tested by its relative stain removing ability).

A suggested path would be to prepare a HOCl/NaOCl mix from the action of CO2 or NaHCO3 on aqueous NaOCl (also available as Chlorine Bleach). This could be converted into a mist/fog, forming a de facto so-called 'Bleach battery' droplet. This is a variation of the 'Bleach Battery' based on HOCl in place of NaOCl, fine carbon soot for the noble cathodic zone (normally copper metal), and for the anode, employ metal particles for the anodic zone (like Al, Zn, Mg, Fe,...).

The battery cell creates electrons and some solvated electrons. In the presence of air (more precisely, oxygen interacting with the mist), I would expect some superoxide radical formation:

$\ce{ O2 + e- (aq) <=> .O2- (aq) }$

which could further react with the hypochlorous acid forming hydroxyl radicals:

$\ce{ .O2- (aq) + HOCl (aq) <=> O2 (g) + .OH (aq) + Cl- (aq)}$ [Reference here.](https://febs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1016/0014-5793(93)80394-A)

Note: The above reaction could already be occurring in your NaCl/H2O electrolysis cell, if accompanied by O2 creation (or existing dissolved oxygen in the water that could be removed by boiling). While this would be disinfecting in the electrolysis cell itself, there would likely be little HOCl left to extract.

Also, in presence of HCO3-, the longer existing and more selective carbon radical anion may be formed:

$\ce{ HCO3- (aq) + .OH (aq) <=> H2O + .CO3- (aq) }$

In addition, the interaction of a transition metal particle with HOCl will also directly form the hydroxyl radical at pH > 5 (hence the use of an alkaline HOCl/NaOCl mix which also lowers the risk of chlorine gas formation). Then, per this reference, "Fenton chemistry in biology and medicine" by Josef Prousek, to quote reaction (15) on page 2330, a general depiction of Fenton-type reactions, to quote:

"For Fe(II) and Cu(I), this situation can be generally depicted as follows [20,39],

$\ce{ Fe(II)/Cu(I) + HOX → Fe(III)/Cu(II) + ·OH + X- }$ (15)

where X = Cl, ONO, and SCN. "

My last comment, this disinfecting process results in a deposit of NaCl/Carbon, and you should avoid all aluminum alloys which will be disfigured by HOCl, and, of course, don't forget the safety precautions. Do not introduce any organics as there is the possibility of chloro-organic creation.

Comment: You completely lost me after the second paragraph; I do not have one hundredth of your know-how, so what I took from your answer (which was still very useful) is: "_use safety precautions while you electrolyze salt water to obtain HOCl; do not worry about final concentration, you will get a solution powerful enough_". After that, my comprehension was blurred.
I just tried testing the stain removal ability with a black marker on plexiglas; my "HOCl solution" removed marker better after some seconds soaking and then frictioning, than what plain salted water did. I'd upvote you if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Ephestione's procedure is not clear.

1. He wants to produce hypochlorous acid $\ce{HOCl}$ by electrolysis of $\ce{NaCl}$. Unfortunately $\ce{HOCl}$ cannot be obtained directly by $\ce{NaCl}$ electrolysis. The  $\ce{NaCl}$ electrolysis produces $\ce{NaOH + H_2}$ at the cathode, and $\ce{Cl_2}$ at the anode (+$\ce{O_2}$ as an impurity). So $\ce{HOCl}$ is not produced here.  Of course a small proportion of $\ce{Cl_2}$ reacts with water to produce $\ce{HClO}$ (and HCl) according to : $$\ce{Cl_2 + H_2O <=> HOCl + H^+ + Cl^-}$$ But a high $\ce{HOCl}$ concentration cannot be obtained this way, because the equilibrium is strongly displaced to the left hand side. If more $\ce{HOCl}$ is to be obtained, some $\ce{NaOH}$ must be added, so as to destroy $\ce{H^+}$, but it will also destroy $\ce{HOCl}$.
2. He wants to separate the anode and the anode compartments, using what he called an "electrode bridge". Never heard about such a thing ! Well. With usual wet junctions made with agar + $\ce{KNO_3}$ solution, the currant going through the cell is rather low. The yield will be weak for reasonable amounts of time, like one or two days, because of the high resistance of the junction, which would limit the currant drastically.  Anyway it does not make sense to separate the two compartments. Using a unique solution with two electrodes, the Chlorine gas produced at the anode would soon react with the NaOH produced at the cathode, yielding a significant amount of $\ce{ClO^-}$ ions by the equation $$\ce{Cl_2 + 2 OH^- ->  ClO^- + Cl^- + H_2O}$$ With this unique solution, a high yield of $\ce{ClO^-}$ ions is produced, which may be acidified to produce significant amounts of $\ce{HClO}$.

Final remarks :

1) if  Ephestione wants to obtain a significant amount of $\ce{HClO}$ in solution, why not use common bleach, which a solution of $\ce{NaClO + NaCl}$, and add some acidic solution ? It would be quicker, safer, without any problems of Iron Oxides.

2) $\ce{HCl}$ is called "hydrochloric acid" and not "chloridric acid".
 "Chloridric" has no meaning. This reminds me of the word "acide chlorhydrique" which is the French translation of "hydrochloric acid".

3) Exposing hypochlorites and $\ce{HClO}$ to air for more than one day, would destroy  them because of the action of atmospheric $\ce{CO_2}$ that reacts according to :
$$\ce{OCl^- + Cl^- + H_2O + 2 CO_2  ->  Cl_2 + 2 HCO_3^-}$$

3) Rust is not $\ce{FeO}$ but $\ce{Fe_2O_3}$ or a a hydrated derivate of $\ce{Fe_2O_3}$

Comment: Thanks!
1. I didn't find it documented anywhere! So I use commercial bleach, add NaCl, and some vinegar, and I obtain HOCl without elecrolysis?

2. I realized it after the editing time window was already closed; I'm italian, and we say "acido cloridrico", much like french, that's why

3. So I need to place the HOCl solution in a sealed container far from sunlight to store it (after having placed it in another sealed container for sedimentation if I elecrolyzed it)

4. Thank you for correcting, I guessed my best and googled the rest, last time I properly studied chemistry was 25 yrs ago

Comment: @Ephestione. No ! Don't add NaCl to Bleach. Use it as such ! Bleach is the result of electrolysis of NaCl solutions with big electrodes which are nearly touching one another. So there is plenty of NaCl in the bleach. If you want it, you may add some acidic solution like vinegar.

Comment: Per a source, to quote: "AQUAOX™ generated HOCL is pH neutral, super-oxidized water generated by electrolysis of a dilute salt solution passing through an electrolytic cell " at https://www.aquaox.com/technology/ . So, it is possible to make dilute HOCl from the electrolysis of salt water.

Comment: The main reseller of HOCl ready solution here in Italy produces it with electrolysis (and sells it for 140€ per 20L...) According to their website, their HOCl solution contains 0.05% of hypoclorous acid in 99.95% of electrolyzed water. Also, electrolysis is the "most affordable" method for a DIYer to produce HOCl that I found by researching online, I never stumbled upon "add acid to bleach" method and that's why I am confused, unless you meant to electrolyze bleach+acid as well. My aim is to obtain a solution safe to nebulize in occupied rooms.